# How to interpret the output of sim() function (package arm)

Tags: r, plot, model, simulation

I want to know how I can interpret the output of the sim() function in the package arm.

From what I understand, the sim() function allows to simulate the distribution of the mean and the variance of a model.

Here is what model I've been working with so far (this model is about birds):

```
Lmm1 <- lmer(active.asinsqrt ~ emigration + sex_genetical + d.time + (1|individualID), data = mergedallactive)
```

The dependent variable is a variable representing the frequency of active behaviors of birds on a daily basis, transformed with asinsqrt for analysis. There are different independent variables with emigration, sex and the time of the day, and a random intercept on the different individuals (correct me if I'm wrong here).

My teacher asked me to use sim() in the package arm to simulate different distributions:

```
nsim <- 5000
bsim <- sim(Lmm1, n.sim = nsim)
str(bsim)
```

I tried with 5000 simulations and the output gave me this result:

```
Formal class 'sim.merMod' [package "arm"] with 3 slots
  ..@ fixef: num [1:5000, 1:4] 0.205 0.202 0.22 0.219 0.222 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "(Intercept)" "emigrationbefore" "sex_geneticalm" "d.time"
  ..@ ranef:List of 1
  .. ..$ individualID: num [1:5000, 1:32, 1] 0.042 0.0469 0.0423 0.0429 0.044 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:32] "Almen18 (eobs 5861)" "Almen19 (eobs 7001)" "Art San Romerio18 (eobs 5941)" "Avers20 (eobs 7101)" ...
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "(Intercept)"
  ..@ sigma: num [1:5000] 0.0884 0.0884 0.0885 0.0888 0.0882 ...
```

I've tried to interpret the results and here is what I think this is:

- The sim function returns the different simulations values (fixef for the fixed effect, ranef for the random effects, sigma for the variance or standard deviation).
- "num" in the fixed effect is representing simulated values of independent variables emigration, d.time and sex_genetical (I don't know if it represents the whole variables or only one).
- "num" in the random effect: I think it represents the simulated values for individuals but it seems strange to me that there are numbers (Individual ID is a character variable).
- "num" in the sigma: I think this is about the variance or standard deviation of the results (but I don't know if it represents the variance or standard deviation of the results for the dependent variable active.asinsqrt or not).

Now for vizualisation I've tried looking at plots:

[image: Here we have the bsim fixed effect plot]

[image: bsim sigma plot]

Both of the codes are very simple:

```
plot(bsim@fixef)
plot(bsim@sigma)
```

Now my question is, after all of my research, I still don't know what I should extract from a sim() function. I don't know if I'm right about what I said, and how I could plot it to be relevant for my analysis.
I know it should be specific to me and what my teacher says but I want to get a big picture of what the sim() function really is about.
Any help please ?
Cheers